# Azure APIM Developer Portal Designer via Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-front-door, azure-nsg

I have APIM with custom domain and NSG set up to allow only access (inbound) from Front Door.
My front door is set up and all is working fine. I can access the developer portal.
However I cannot access the developer portal designer (the 'Developer Portal' button on the APIM overview page). When I remove NSG the button is working - taking me to the developer portal designer, but going via FD always gets me to developer portal home page, not designer:

> This is a home page of the Developer portal - an automatically generated....

I also tried to set up Azure AD in Identities tab, adding my FD domain to app registration return url, but the effect is the same.

Any idea how I can launch the designer via FD?

Comment: Can you share your NSG setup?  Also, to clarify, it sounds like when you remove the NSG and try to go to the developer portal designer via Front Door it actually directs you to the developer portal home page instead of the developer portal designer, correct?

Comment: @Narthring the nsg is pretty standard is just allow FD and vnet and deny everything else. Yes all requests from FD always go to the home page. The only way to launch designer is via the button in APIM overview page, but with NSG in place it's blocked.

Comment: How are you allowing FD in the NSG?  I assume you're using the AzureFrontDoor.Backend service tag to allow traffic?